# List ALL states within States Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, states

How can I get an array of all possible states from my CardHolderStateMachine?

So far I only have two (`:pending` and `:active`) but I want to grab them to use in a dropdown.

```
class CardHolderStateMachine
  include Statesman::Machine

  state :pending, initial: true
  state :active

  transition from: :pending, to: [:active]
```

By "states" I don't mean States of America (just to avoid confusion as there are a few posts about that which have nothing to do with [Statesman](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `CardHolderStateMachine.states`?

```
 > CardHolderStateMachine.states
=> ["pending", "active"]
```

It always pays off to check the [source code](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman/blob/master/lib/statesman/machine.rb#L30).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yeah that works perfectly. Quite new to Rails and find it hard looking through the source code. I did try looking here; https://github.com/gocardless/statesman/blob/master/lib/statesman.rb